# Is it possible to pipe extracted 'img%d.jpg' images from ffmpeg to another software without saving image anywhere?

Tags: python, image-processing, ffmpeg, video-processing, io-redirection

I am extracting images using command:

```
ffmpeg -i video -r 5 img%d.jpg
```

and i want to pipe each image to another executable directly without saving file anywhere.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2):

You can get ffmpeg to write data to stdout and then consume that with another app.

`ffmpeg -i video -r 5 -c:v mjpeg -f image2pipe pipe:1 | otherapp`

The `1` after `pipe:` is the file descriptor.

Comment: Just checking... this will send a continuous stream of concatenated JPEGs to otherapp, won't it? There's no direct/obvious way to start a new otherapp for each image?

Comment: Yeah, that's not possible.